# Cosa significa "calare l'asso" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto:

> Barontini **cala l'asso**: il *dinamitero* asturiano José Velázquez Calero che di fratelli caduti in quella guerra ne aveva avuti due; moglie e figlia seviziate e uccise dai marocchini del Tercio di Franco. Lo lasciamo dietro una tenda a preparare religiosamente una mina da chili dodici intenzionato a depositarla ai piedi della torretta.

Il brano fa riferimento alla guerra di Spagna.

Ho cercato alla voce "asso" su parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa espressione. Ho visto, però, che ci sono molti modi di dire con la parola "asso". Si tratta anche questo di un modo di dire? Cosa significa nel contesto del passaggio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Calare l'asso" è un'espressione derivante dai giochi di carte: spesso l'asso è la carta di maggior valore, quindi in senso figurato significa utilizzare la propria migliore tecnica, o il proprio migliore strumento. Assume anche una caratteristica di sorpresa, in quanto giocare questa carta ha grande effetto e può cambiare le sorti della partita.

Nel caso di questo brano, "Barontini cala l'asso" può essere reso come "Barontini fa la mossa decisiva" o "Barontini fa una mossa a sorpresa".

Un'espressione simile (più comune) è "avere un asso nella manica", che significa avere, appunto, la possibilità di "calare l'asso".

Per esempio, "Credeva di aver vinto, ma l'avversario aveva un asso nella manica".

Comment: Potrebbe riferirsi alla briscola, dove l'asso ha il valore più alto, oppure allo scopone, dove l'asso piglia tutte le carte sulla tavola.